# unable to know doesNotRecognizeSelector _cmd

Tags: iphone

Can any one advice me what doesNotRecognizeSelect _cmd will do

```
- (NSDictionary*)Event:(EventBase*)eventBase
{
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}
```

`[self doesNotRecognizeSelect:_cmd];`  There is no self method invocation but its calling, Can any one have idea about _cmd to doesNotRecognizeSelect

Comment: I assume you're trying to enforce an abstract class or something? Better to throw an exception explicitly if you really need to do this, doing this will just make things very confusing. Also, capitalized Objective-C method names are a plague on the community, please stop :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)doesNotRecognizeSelector:(SEL)aSelector
```

aSelector which is _cmd

it states that method is not implemented or recognized by the receiver.

The runtime system invokes this method whenever an object receives an aSelector message it can’t respond to or forward. This method, in turn, raises an NSInvalidArgumentException, and generates an error message.

```
- (id)copy
{
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
}
```

The _cmd variable is a hidden argument passed to every method that is the current selector; in this example, it identifies the selector for the copy method. This code prevents instances of the subclass from responding to copy messages or superclasses from forwarding copy messages—although respondsToSelector: will still report that the receiver has access to a copy method.